# É possível comparar duas variáveis vindos de uma view no Django?

Tags: python, django

Bem, eu quero comparar duas variáveis vindos de uma view no Django. Estou fazendo um for e iterando e comparando um valor do tipo CharField (aluno.matricula) com outro CharField (frequencia.matricula)! Queria saber se é possível fazer isso. O meu resultado sempre cai no else!

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>Turma</td>
    <td>Matrícula</td>
    <td>Nome</td>
    <td>Faltas</td>
    <td>Data com hora</td>
</tr>
{% for aluno in alunos_tsi %}
<tr>
    <td>TSI</td>
    <td>{{ aluno.matricula }}</td>
    <td>{{ aluno.nome }}</td>
        {% for frequencia in frequencias %}
            {% if frequencia.matricula == aluno.matricula %}
                <td>{{ frequencia.faltas }}</td>
                <td>{{ frequencia.data_com_hora }}</td>
            {% else %}
                <td>0</td>
                <td>Nenhuma frequência registrada</td>
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
    </td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
```

Comment: Aqui não escrevemos "resolvido" na questão. Se tem uma resposta que realmente te ajudou, marque-a como aceita. Se chegou sozinho à solução, poste a solução como resposta. Assim o conteúdo fica mais organizado e fácil de ser encontrado futuramente por outras pessoas com problemas parecidos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Segundo a documentação](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/templates/builtins/#operator) é possível sim. Sugiro que debug o código pra observar se a condição está sendo atendida.

Comment: Obrigado pela atenção. Já resolvi o problema, abraço.

Answer (score 1):

Tente usar a seguinte comparação:

```
{% ifequal frequencia.matricula|stringformat:"s" aluno.matricula %}
...
{% endifequal %}
```

ou talvez esse:

```
{% ifequal frequencia.matricula|stringformat:"s" aluno.matricula|stringformat:"s" %}

...
{% endifequal %}
```

Retirado desse [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16995256/3191313)